# How to upload file with the 10GB+ size in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload file with size more than 10GB+ and there is multiple files that i want to upload at the server.

I made some changes in `Web.config` to upload large files.

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="6000000" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

But it only support the file size up to 2GB. I do too much research but I can not get anything that help me to upload 10GB+ file size.

I read some article that said that the maximum file size limit is `2GB`

[Maximum value of maxRequestLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548305/maximum-value-of-maxrequestlength)

[IIS 7 httpruntime maxRequestLength limit of 2097151](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288682/iis-7-httpruntime-maxrequestlength-limit-of-2097151)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/prashant_upadhyay/2011/07/12/large-file-upload-issue-in-asp-net/

I found some hacks that I slice the file at the client side (browser) and upload that all the slice at the server and after that i merge all that slice to single file.

But this may be wrong idea to do that, If some slice of file is failed to upload or missed so file may be corrupted.

I don't want to implement the `Slice and Upload and Merge`  file technique to upload large file.

There is any another way to do the Upload Larger files (10GB+ size) with the ASP.NET and C#.

Thanks.

Comment: FTP is good idea but I have to provide the interface to client with in website to upload files and that file is not simple file. I have to extract the content of the file and perform the extra task depending on the content of the file. Thanks @Pikoh

Answer (score 0):

only use this

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="6000000" maxRequestLength="10485760"/>
</system.web>
```

remove below code from web.config

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and 10gb = 10485760 kb

Comment: This will not work because `maxRequestLength` only except the bytes and it's type is `int32` so it can not upload 10GB file. If I set as you said so it only upload the `10MB` file

Comment: I will never remove the code of block that you said. Because I am using `Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0` and after the `Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0+` that code of block is needed..